# Problems with CURL in Laravel 10 as of today local

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I've been having since today problems with CURL when executing functions with an API in Laravel that calls zoho, last time I tested it last night at 2 am and today it stopped working.

I get the following message:

```
cURL error 28: Failed to connect to projectsapi.zoho.com port 443: Timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portals/

AND

cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10008 milliseconds (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portals/
```

The calls were working I haven't made any modifications, I just turned on my notebook today and the error appeared in the project which is still in local and not in production.

Attached is the same code

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Generamos y refrescamos los tokens
        $this->token = ZohoOauth::latest()->first()?->auth_token;
        // return $this->token;
        // Obtenemos el ID del portal.
        $this->getAllPortals();
    }

    public function getAllPortals(){
        $portals = $this->getCallApi('portals/');
        // $this->checkToken($portals);

        // Guardamos el ID del portal
        if (count($portals->portals) > 0) {
            foreach ($portals->portals as $key => $portal) {
                $this->portalID = $portal->id;
            }
        }

        return $this->portalID;
    }

    public function getCallApi($url)
    {
        // dd($url,$parameters);
        try {
            $response = Http::withHeaders(['Authorization'=> $this->token])->get(self::URL_API.$url);
            dd($response->body());
            return json_decode($response->body());
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            //throw $th;
            dd($th);
        }
    }
```

I forgot to mention that in POSTMAN the methods are working, but in Laravel it stopped working, I thought it could be a problem with Largon or PHP 8.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the curl URL that you are trying to connect is down or wrong. Check via terminal if the URL is correct.

```
ping google.com
PING google.com(lhr48s48-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4009:826::200e)) 56  data bytes
64 bytes from lhr48s48-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4009:826::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=2.84 ms
```